# "Replace" Vs "Be replaced"

Tags: grammaticality, difference

As you know the verb ["to replace somebody / something"](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/replace) means "to take the place of somebody / something" or "to supersede somebody / something." I was wondering what form is correct in the following sentences? If both are correct, then what is the meaning of each sentence if I want to paraphrase them?

**Example 1:**

The previous teacher is a little old and cannot manage to come to the school on a daily basis and now:

> **1.a.** **I'm being replaced** with him.
>   **1.b.** **I am replacing** with him.

For more clarification, let me bring up another example:

**Example 1:**

> **2.a.** In modern life, email **has been replaced** the traditional business letter.
>   **2.b.** In modern life, email **has replaced** the traditional business letter.

**Note:** as we know, the verb "replace" is a transitive verb. So it cannot be used in a passive tone. These all are confusing me a little! Maybe I am missing something here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Replace" is, as you say, a transitive verb, and therefore **can** be used in the passive:

> A replaces B
>
> B is replaced by A.

It can also be used as a causative verb:

> C replaces B with A (eg *My boss wants to replace me with a machine!*)
>
> B is replaced by C with A. (eg *That poster is being replaced by the creative director, with this new one*. A comma is not always necessary in this structure, but often makes it clearer)

Your 1a and 2b make sense. Your 1b and 2a are incoherent.

Comment: It seems to be an excellent answer and perhaps what I need @Colon Fine, but I cannot understand the role of the C and the meaning of "by" / "with" in causative form! I'm absolutely confused. Please kindly simplify / paraphrase these strictures.

Comment: @A-friend: I've added some examples: does that help?